# ChatRoom client ip address c++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a chat room app with c++ using Qt and I figured that all the clients have the same IP address '127.0.0.1' (localhost address). Consequently, when a client sends a message, all the connected clients to the server receive it.
I don't know how to deal with this!!
Am I getting something wrong? Please help.

Comment: The behaviour you describe sounds like what one would expect from a chat room. "127.0.0.1" is just an IP address that you can use to send messages to "this machine" - when you send to "127.0.0.1", nothing even gets outside the originating computer. When one computer sends something to another, they use the "proper" IP addresses assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

The 127.0.0.1 is the localhost IP address, remote clients would have their own. However the IP address is not a unique enough identifier, many clients could be behind a NAT'ed Internet connection.

When someone connects, you also need to assign them a unique identifier and then use that as the means of tracking where messages are sent.

Comment: Is it a good idea to use the port number as a unique client identifier?

Comment: @DouaeHaddad Nope, there is a very limited number of ports and anybody could connect. You'd generally connect with an email address, the server would then generate a UUID (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/quuid.html) for the connection. The two combined are enough for the server to keep track of individual users.